# Как изменить размер изображения в canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть объект `canvas`. Как изменить его ширину сохраняя пропорции?
Затем я его преобразую в готовый код image.

```
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Нужно вычислить первоначальное соотношение сторон `t = width/heigth`. Установить новую ширину  - высоту умножить на первоначальное соотношение `height *t`

Comment: Нет, меня интересует не алгоритм,  а какую функцию вызывать.

Comment: Я о такой функции  не слышал. В канвасе все самому надо делать)